# Closing an RStudio project programmatically

Tags: r, rstudio

The `rstudioapi`package has a function `openProject()` with which one can **non-interactively** open an existing R Studio project.

In fact, there are functions in the same package for initializing/creating R Studio projects. However, I could not find anything in the documentation for closing or shutting down a project and moving into a regular R session.

How can this be done, if at all?

Comment: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/rstudioapi/vignettes/projects.html says you can reopen the same project, or move to another. That indirectly closes the project for another.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. What I want is not to have any other active `.Rproj`

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that.  I suspect the RStudio people would say that working in a project *is* the regular way to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this. I'd suggest filing an issue on the rstudioapi package issues page if you'd like to request the feature:

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudioapi/issues

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is old, but for those still looking, [there is a function now](https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/1.3.947-1/rstudio-ide-commands.html) using the `rstudioapi` package:

```
rstudioapi::executeCommand('closeProject')
```